# Each Cell need to have a Section - Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm implementing a Feed on my App using Parse.com, basically I'm populating a `UITableViewController` and everything works fine, BUT, I really like the way Instagram does, seems like the Instagram have a UIView inside each cell that works like a `header` and that view follows the scroll till the end of cell, I tried to search about that and I'm not successful, after some research I've realized that this feature is equally a Section, so I decide to implement Sections in my querys, I've implemented the code below:

```
import UIKit




class FeedTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadCollectionViewData()

}


func loadCollectionViewData() {

    // Build a parse query object
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Feed")

    // Check to see if there is a search term


    // Fetch data from the parse platform
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // The find succeeded now rocess the found objects into the countries array
        if error == nil {

             print(objects!.count)
            // reload our data into the collection view


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

    }
}
}



// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Feed"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objects!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}

//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! FeedTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = FeedTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    cell.anuncerPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.anuncerPhoto.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.anuncerPhoto.clipsToBounds = true

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let nameEnglish = object?["name"] as? String {
        cell?.title?.text = nameEnglish

    }

    let thumbnail = object?["Photo"] as! PFFile
    let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "loadingImage")
    cell.photoImage.image = initialThumbnail
    cell.photoImage.file = thumbnail
    cell.photoImage.loadInBackground()

    return cell
}  
}
```

Basically I will need to have a section for each cell, Now I'm successfully have sections working for each cell, but the problem is that the querys is repeating on the first post.

In the backend I have 3 different posts, so, in the App the UItableview need to have 3 posts with different content, with the code above I'm successfully counting the number of posts to know how many section I'll need to have and I declare that I want one post per section, but the app shows 3 sections with the same first post.

Any ideas if I'm capture the correct concept of the Instagram feature and why I'm facing this problem in my querys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the original UITableViewDataSource method and retrieve the current object using the indexPath.section

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! FeedTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = FeedTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    cell.anuncerPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.anuncerPhoto.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.anuncerPhoto.clipsToBounds = true


    let object = objects[indexPath.section]

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let nameEnglish = object["name"] as? String {
        cell?.title?.text = nameEnglish

    }

    let thumbnail = object["Photo"] as! PFFile
    let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "loadingImage")
    cell.photoImage.image = initialThumbnail
    cell.photoImage.file = thumbnail
    cell.photoImage.loadInBackground()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Worked ! I follow your instruction and this solved my problem, but generate another, maybe you could teach me again, I opened another question: [Here viewforheaderinsection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535442/dynamic-viewforheaderinsection-and-multiple-cellforrowatindexpath)